# Как сохранить состояние Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-button

У меня в Acitivty есть кнопка, которая создаётся динамически. Но если я перейду на другую Activity, и обратно, кнопка исчезает. Как сделать так, чтобы она там была, даже если я и перехожу на другое Activity?

Comment: Вам нужно сохранять состояние в `onSaveInstanceState`, и затем в `onRestoreInstanceState` его восстановить. Сохраните флаг, который будет указывать на то, показывать кнопку или нет.

Comment: @NikitaRemnev Можете в ответе подробно написать, как это сделать, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно сохранять состояние в `onSaveInstanceState`, и затем в `onRestoreInstanceState` восстановить это состояние. Полный пример:

**TestActivity.java**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout dynamicButtonContainer;

    private boolean isButtonShowing = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        dynamicButtonContainer = findViewById(R.id.container);

        findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addDynamicButton();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.start).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(TestActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("is_button_showed", isButtonShowing);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("is_button_showed", false)) {
            addDynamicButton();
        }
    }

    private void addDynamicButton() {
        if (!isButtonShowing) {
            Button addedButton = new Button(TestActivity.this);
            dynamicButtonContainer.addView(addedButton);
            isButtonShowing = true;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: В качестве флага можете завести переменную, которой нужно ставить значение true, когда кнопка показывается (также ставить true, когда кнопка добавляется через onRestoreInstanceState), либо если Ваша кнопка является полем класса, можно просто проверить ее на null

Comment: У меня кнопка создана динамически. Как я могу добавить к ней переменную?

Comment: Просто я новичок :)

Comment: Приложите код Вашей Activity, так проще будет подсказать)

Comment: Добавьте в Activity поле: private boolean isButtonShowing = false; и присваивайте isButtonShowing = true, в момент добавления кнопки. После в onSaveInstanceState outState.putBoolean("is_button_showed", isButtonShowing)

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Можете написать, как сделать флаг? Да, знаю, глупые вопросы :) Но я, к сожалению, не понимаю принцип работы этого кода.

Comment: @Александр дополнил ответ

Comment: Помогите мне ещё, пожалуйста :). Проблема в том, что кнопки не будут прописаны в разметке.

Comment: А можно ли это как-то сделать через onCreate?

Comment: Что именно сделать через onCreate? Восстановление состояния? Да, можно, но тогда нужно обязательно добавить проверку savedInstanceState != null.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83774/discussion-between--and-nikita-remnev).